# Business bank account for a UK visa

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

Will I get refused a UK visit visa if I do not have a bank account registered in the name of my business? My husband does not have a separate business bank account. In Pakistan, most of the sole proprietor businesses are run with personal bank accounts. I am confused that how will they treat our application when we are attaching all personal account bank statements.

Comment: Do you have proof of the income and expenses which can be tallied with the inflow and outflow in the bank accounts ?

Comment: @Marium Reading this might help https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab

Comment: @DumbCoder I am attaching the bank statements, Tax Returns and Business registration documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running business finances through a personal bank account is not a reason to refuse a visa.

To echo what dumbcoder says, you need to evidence that the money is genuinely available for you to spend and that it is legitimately obtained (not via criminal activity).